# Turn off fringe character for org-capture

Tags: org-capture, bookmarks, fringe, emacs28

I updated to Emacs 28 recently and org-capture now puts a small character in the left fringe for captured items. I know that I can set `fringe-mode` to `no-fringe` to not see any fringe, but that's not what I want. I want to specifically turn off or set to `nil` the fringe character for org-capture.

System: Emacs 28.1, Org 9.5.2

To reproduce:

```
emacs -Q
M-: (setq org-capture-templates '(("t" "Todo" entry (file ~/test.org) "* TODO item")))
M-x org-capture t
C-c C-c
C-x C-f ~/test.org
```

[image: screenshot showing fringe character to the left of captured text]

I read in the manual about [fringe indicators](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Fringe-Indicators.html), so I tried setting all bitmap values in `fringe-indicator-alist` to `nil`, but that didn't work. There are [some other answers](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/search?q=fringe) about fringe indicators, but they indicated that `fringe-indicator-alist` was the place that fringes are set. None of them were helpful for my problem related to org-capture.

Where is this fringe character set? How do I remove it without turning off `fringe-mode` entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Org Capture sets a bookmark for the last stored item. The bookmark library is responsible for setting this fringe mark, not org. Check out the option `bookmark-set-fringe-mark`, which was introduced in 28.1.

Comment: Thanks! This is my first time hearing about bookmarks. It looks like another option to solve this problem would be `org-capture-bookmark`.